# Android - zipalign fails before apksigner

Tags: android, gradle, build, zipalign, apksigner

I'm currently in the process of upgrading from V1 signing (`jarsigner`) to V2 signing (`apksigner`). Jarsigner has been working for me no problem, however I'm running into issues with `zipalign` in my build.gradle before I can run `apksigner`.

On command line, I know there is a hack to `zipalign` twice, which works for me.

However, when I am running `zipalign` on Jenkins, I have been getting this error:

> Process 'command '/Users/admin/Library/Android/sdk/build-tools/27.0.1/zipalign'' **finished with non-zero exit value 1**

What can I do to make `zipalign` work so I can use `apksigner`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to come to the solution with a try-catch. It's ugly, but it works.

```
try {
    println "Zipaligning ${apkFile.name}"
    exec {
        commandLine zipalign, '-f', '4', apkFile.canonicalPath, tempAPK.canonicalPath
    }
} catch (err) {
    // Zipalign twice if first zipalign fails
    exec {
        commandLine zipalign, '-f', '4', tempAPK.canonicalPath, signedAPK.canonicalPath
    }
}
```